# How to map objectProxy Returned by HTTPService to valueobjects

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, httpservice

I am using HTTPService component to call the webservice. I am getting the result in resulthandler but result type is objectProxy. I want to convert them to my value objects which I generated using Data/Service of Flash builder. [image]
I am not able to access the ConnectUserAccess (as shown in attached image) as the Value Object.

```
var hs:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
var url:String = ConfigManager.getProperty("user.project.acess");
 hs.method = "GET";
 hs.url = url;
 hs.resultFormat = "object";
 var params:Object = {};
 params["User_Name"] = "madhur";
 hs.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, getProjectsAccessHandler);
 hs.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, getProjectFaultHandler);
 hs.send(params);

private function getProjectsAccessHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
 var connect:ConnectUserAccess = event.result.ConnectUserAccess;
}
```

Comment: This usually means you've not got your RemoteClass metadata set up correctly.

Comment: ValueObjects are my remote class objects. They are generated by Data/Services feature of Flash builder. I don't think this could be the issue. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reference to the VO anywhere in your ActionScript code? (Is there an `import my.package.MyVO;` statement and a reference `MyVo;` anywhere in the code?)

Comment: @Gregor Kiddie @RIAstar HTTPService won't automatically convert server side objects to ActionScript objects.  @Madhur will either have to switch to using RemoteObject w/ an AMF Gateway or manually do a conversion.  IF he were using RemoteObject, though, you both have nailed two good things to check if if the conversion doesn't work when using an AMF Gateway.

Comment: Yes, I have imported valueObject package and it's classes. I've observed one more thing. If I do it in mxml file using callResponder class then it works fine, the result in an valueObject. All I had to do is to generate service call from flash builder's Data/Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work. Mistake I was doing was creating HTTPservice Object even though I have generated the service class using Data/Service feature of flash builder. 
I only had to use the generated service class to make a call to Httpservice. Now all I want is to get the event back from the service. The generated service returns me mx.rpc.AsyncToken which I can consume using callResponder.token. See the code below to get more clarity.

```
import services.release.Release;
[Bindable]
private var userCR:CallResponder;
[Bindable]
private var release :Release;
private function init():void{
userCR = new CallResponder;
userCR.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, getUserProject);
userCR.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,getUserProjectFaultHandler);
release = new Release;
}
protected function userProjectAccess(User_Name:String, User_GUID:String):void
{
userCR.token = Release.UserProjectAccess(User_Name, User_GUID);
}
```

Call this function userProjectAccess wherever required.

Comment: Similar problem has taken so much time of mine. Different methods of generated service behaves different. Some times it returns String, sometime object proxy. I configured the return type as string via wizard of FB and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do a manual conversion.  Only RemoteObject (AKA AMF) will automatically convert your server side side object to an ActionScript object.  Using HTTPService will not make the conversion.

You should be able to do a manual "cast" like this:

```
private function getProjectsAccessHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
 var connect:ConnectUserAccess = event.result.ConnectUserAccess as ConnectUserAccess;
}
```

Comment: @Madhur Can you access individual properties on the object?  If so, you can do a manual conversion; property by property.